# SetOutputFile in MediaRecorder in Storage Access Framework

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I want to use the Storage Access Framework (SAF) on Android with MediaRecorder. But under the SAF scheme, you should not rely on absolute path, but rather on Uri that you previously took permissions for.

What is the good way to work, how can one use MediaRecorder consistently with the new approach of Android's SAF?
Let's say, as a (well documented) starting point you start from here:

```
List<UriPermission> permission=  getContentResolver().getPersistedUriPermissions();
```

And you want to get there:

```
mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(/*Some arguments*/);
mMediaRecorder.prepare();
```

What are the intermediate steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to try `openFileDescriptor()` on `ContentResolver`, to get a `FileDescriptor` on the content identified by the `Uri`. Then, pass that to the version of `setOutputFile()` on `MediaRecorder` that takes a `FileDescriptor`. How well this will work will depend a lot on what you are recording and whether the documents provider supports seeking (which pretty much boils down to whether this `Uri` is backed by a regular file).

Comment: openFileDescriptor returns a android.net.ParcelFileDescriptor and setOutputFile takes a java.io.FileDescriptor. From what I see, the system does not allows the conversion. Am I missing something? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, ok, I remember, I did tried this a moment ago:        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(mUri,"rwt").getFileDescriptor();    But then I get a  this:         E/JavaBinder: *** Uncaught remote exception!  (Exceptions are not yet supported across processes.)
                                               java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=21; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
                                                   at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength...

Comment: @SylOR: I do not know what that message might mean. FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Media/AudioRecordStream) shows using a `FileDescriptor` with `MediaRecorder`. In my case, I'm using a `ParcelFileDescriptor` pipe, which does not support seeking. My sample works because I am recording `RAW_AMR`, which does not require seeking. In the end, if the `FileDescriptor` approach does not work, you may need to record first to a regular file, then copy the media to the content identified by the `Uri`.

Comment: It did work. My problem mostly lied in the way I was using DcumentsContract methods. Thanks a lot.