# getExternalStoragePublicDirectory deprecated in Android Q. How to save document file into public directory?

Tags: android

I want to get access to public directory files, for storing not: image, audio and video!
I need to store: documents (for example: doc, pdf, bak, zip, etc...).
I need these documents should stay on user device even after my app will be uninstalled. And I need user can access these document files from other apps.

In early versions of android, for documents folder, I can simply write down next line:

```
File myDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "My documents");
if (!myDirectory.exists()) {
   if(myDirectory.mkdirs()){
      // directory exists, can place any files here                
   }
}
```

How can I do this in android Q? 
Or no way, and I just need to tell my users that my app doesnt support Android 10 at all?

p.s.
I see this:
[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory deprecated in Android Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539/getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-deprecated-in-android-q/58129623#58129623)
- No answer for my question

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do this in android Q?

Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose a location, and then store your content at the `Uri` that you get.

Or, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` to allow the user to choose a tree (e.g., directory). You can use the `Uri` that you get back with `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` to be able to create child documents. In each case, you wind up with a `Uri` that you can use to store the content.

Given a `Uri`, you can use `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to write the content to the location identified by the `Uri`.

[This sample Java app](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-java/tree/v0.5/ContentEditor) (and [its Kotlin counterpart](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-jetpack-kotlin/tree/v0.5/ContentEditor)) demonstrate how to work with files and content `Uri` values. I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to pick an existing text file or `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to create a new text file.

Comment: Can I do this without requesting additional UI dialogs to user?

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights: No, sorry. The point behind these changes is to put the user in charge of storage.

Comment: This is a disaster :-((((

Comment: ...it's just like on my PC: I save txt file in one folder with notepad. And can not open it for example with wordpad, word, etc...
This is completely unbelievable situation.

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights: "I save txt file in one folder with notepad" -- last I checked, the Windows Notepad program uses a "file save" dialog to allow the user to choose where to save the file and what to call it. That is what `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` does. "And can not open it for example with wordpad, word, etc.." -- last I checked, those programs use a "file open" dialog to allow the user to pick a document to open. That is what `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` does.

Comment: It was an example if you dont understand... Try to imagine notepad with default directory for saving files

Comment: @RussiaDroneFlights: "Try to imagine notepad with default directory for saving files" -- last I checked, Notepad does not have a default directory for saving files. It always asks the user via a file save dialog. Admittedly, I do not use Notepad much, as I do not use Windows much, so perhaps they changed the UX in recent years.

Comment: Ok, I understand :)

Comment: This is indeed a disgusting situation caused by the whacky Android Q!  When the user can easily remove the permission to write externally, why the eff Android is causing so much unnecessary trouble for the users as well as the developers?  Just to copy iOS which has a horrible user experience?!