# copy audio file working on emulator but not working on android device

Tags: java, android, audio

my code below worked with emulator (android 11 & api 30).

```
private void copy(File in, File out) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream is = null;
        FileOutputStream os = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(in);
            os = new FileOutputStream(out);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
                Log.d("AAA", String.valueOf(out.length()));
            }
        } finally {
            assert is != null;
            is.close();
            assert os != null;
            os.close();
        }
    }
```

where i put this method

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String path = RealPathUtil.getRealPath(SetVoiceIntroActivity.this, data.getData());
            File in = new File(path);
            File out = new File(getFilesDir(), "record.mp3");

            try {
                copy(in, out);
                Log.d(TAG, out.getAbsolutePath());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            binding.voicePlayerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.buttonDeleteVoice.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            binding.voicePlayerView.setAudio(out.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

but when i try with my phone it have a problem. how can i fix it?

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.yolo.hopel, PID: 19152
    java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.yolo.hopel.Activities.SetProfile.SetVoiceIntroActivity.copy(SetVoiceIntroActivity.java:251)
        at com.yolo.hopel.Activities.SetProfile.SetVoiceIntroActivity.onActivityResult(SetVoiceIntroActivity.java:64)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5184)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

i catch it and i get the message

```
2021-08-03 19:29:10.310 25013-25013/com.yolo.hopel D/error: /storage/emulated/0/NCT/NgayKhacLa-DenDJGiangPhamTripleD-5393909.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

but i checked permission before

```
binding.buttonSetVoiceGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                checkPermission();
            }
        });
```

```
private void checkPermission() {
        PermissionListener permissionlistener = new PermissionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPermissionGranted() {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("audio/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPermissionDenied(List<String> deniedPermissions) {
                Toast.makeText(SetVoiceIntroActivity.this, "Permission Denied\n" + deniedPermissions.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        TedPermission.with(this)
                .setPermissionListener(permissionlistener)
                .setDeniedMessage("If you reject permission,you can not use this service\n\nPlease turn on permissions at [Setting] > [Permission]")
                .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                .check();
    }
```

i'm sorry but my post is mostle code, i must add some text...
please help me, **thanks everyone and have a nice day!**

Comment: add `catch(Exception e)` before finally and you will find cause of why these streams are `null` (if you still won't be able to figure this out then post new exception stacktrace in question)

Comment: i will. thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a nice uri and then you mess around with all kind of untrusty code to obtain a file path to use FileInputStream for it.

Completely unnecessary.

Open an inputstream for the obtained uri and use it as it was your fileinputstream.

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver.openInputStream(data.getData());
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I learning about resolver. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

An `AssertionError` is thrown when the programmer thinks that something has happened which he/she didn't expect it to happen. So mostly this seems like a `ScopedStorage` issue to me since you explicitly mentioned the case with `Android 11`. You can try reading about the scoped storage in Android . Also the `RealPathUtil` that you used for github doesn't work for the scoped storage case

You can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62879112/9722336) answer for some commonly needed operations for Files using Scoped Storage

Some other points you may need to know about Scoped Storage

- The `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission is deprecated and it is replaced by the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` which is allowed on Play Store after manual approval by Google. You can now access all the publically available files in Android after Q without need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_PERMISSION`. So you must not request the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission unless you're building a File Explorer or anything like that
- You can write to these public directories using the `MediaStore` class if you need explicit access to external storage, if not then you can use `context.getFilesDir()` which gives you app private access to the external storage under the `/data/data/yourpackagename` directory. You must manage this space explicitly
- If you need temporary file storage, you should prefer using `context.getCacheDir()` and the space here will be managed by Android itself
- Under no circumstances, you can get access to the app specific directory, even after you have `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: i catch my error and i get the message "open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)" but i checked permission before. can you help me, please

Comment: As I had said, I suspect this is the error for Scoped Storage and it is exactly that, which directory are you trying to access?

Comment: intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("audio/*");

Comment: i dont know what name it. but i want access to all audio file on device

Comment: I am afraid, you can't do that on ScopedStorage from Android 11 onwards ,please read the docs regarding the same. [Here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) you can find the link regarding the same. The permission `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` is no longer valid

Comment: i will. thanks you so much! have a nice day!

Comment: `context.getExternalFilesDir() which gives you app private access to the external storage under the /data/data/yourpackagename directory. ` No. That path is from getFilesDir().

Comment: Hey @blackapps, made the edits, thank you

Comment: Thanks you so much. I recognize i need learn so much