# Showing media file in gallery

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediascanner

I am downloading file from my server. Due to **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** is deprecated
*To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices* I am saving the video file to the app folder (Android/data/com.myapp/Videos) using getExternalFilesDir.

What I need is this folder (Videos) will be visible in the gallery, or the file will be visible, either way. But my code does not seem to work:

```
    val mainPath = requireActivity().getExternalFilesDir(null)!!.path + "/"
    val path = "$mainPath/Videos/clip1.mp4"

    val values = ContentValues(3)
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, "My video title")
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
    values.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, path)
    
    requireActivity().contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)
```

Comment: For what are you using that .insert() uri? It has nothing to do with saving files to getExternalFilesDir(). What are you doing?

Comment: The file is already located in the path. I just need it to be visible in the gallery.

Comment: These may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57649669/3466808, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62879112/3466808.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code and pass your saved file location here. This will work for Images and Video files. It'll work fine for videos but for images try 'Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM' or 'Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES'

```
   fun Context.saveFileFromExternalStorageToScopedStorage(file: String): String {
    loge { "Downloaded File path: $file" }
    val lastPathSegment = file.toUri().lastPathSegment
        val sourceFile = File(file)
        var destinationDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
        if (!lastPathSegment.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            if (lastPathSegment.contains(".mp4")) {
            destinationDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES)
            }
        }

        loge { "destinationDir: $destinationDir SourceFile isExist: ${sourceFile.exists()}" }

        
    if (sourceFile.exists() && destinationDir != null) {
        val destinationFile =File(destinationDir, "$lastPathSegment")

        try {
            FileInputStream(sourceFile).use { inputStream ->
                FileOutputStream(destinationFile).use { outputStream ->
                    val buffer = ByteArray(4 * 1024)
                    var read: Int
                    while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
                    }
                }
            }

            // Media file copied successfully
            MediaScanner(this, destinationFile).connect()
            return destinationFile.path
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return file
        }
    return file
   }
```

> MediaScanner Class To scanFile

```
   class MediaScanner(val mContext: Context, val file: File) : MediaScannerConnectionClient {

    private var mediaScannerConnection: MediaScannerConnection =
        MediaScannerConnection(mContext, this)

    override fun onScanCompleted(path: String?, uri: Uri?) {
        loge { "onScanCompleted: Path: $path URI: $uri" }
        mediaScannerConnection.disconnect()
    }

    override fun onMediaScannerConnected() {
        mediaScannerConnection.scanFile(file.path, null)
    }

    fun connect() {
        loge { "Connect file to scan: $file" }
        mediaScannerConnection.connect()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is another answer that will work fine for Media Files. This will show your downloaded files into the gallery.

```
// Function to read a media file as a string path and store it in Scoped Storage
fun saveMediaFileToScopedStorage(context: Context, mediaFilePath: String, mimeType: String): Uri? {
    val contentResolver: ContentResolver = context.contentResolver

    // Create a ContentValues object to store the file's metadata
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, File(mediaFilePath).name)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType)
        put(
            MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
            if (mimeType.startsWith("image/")) Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES + File.separator + "yourDirectory/"
            else Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + File.separator + "yourDirectory/"
        )
    }

    // Determine the appropriate MediaStore collection based on the file's MIME type
    val mediaCollection: Uri = when {
        mimeType.startsWith("image/") -> MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        mimeType.startsWith("video/") -> MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported MIME type: $mimeType")
    }

    // Insert the content values into MediaStore to create a new file
    val uri = contentResolver.insert(mediaCollection, contentValues)

    uri?.let { mediaUri ->
        try {
            // Open an InputStream to read the media file
            val inputStream = FileInputStream(mediaFilePath)

            // Open an OutputStream to write the media file to the newly created MediaStore URI
            val outputStream = contentResolver.openOutputStream(mediaUri)

            inputStream.use { input ->
                outputStream?.use { output ->
                    input.copyTo(output)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            return null
        }
    }

    return uri
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Files in getExternalFilesDir() will not be scanned by the media store.

And hence will not be shown by Gallery apps.

Comment: So, the question is how to make file that already on SD card to be scanned by media store?

Comment: No, as the mediastore will not scan your file there. I already told you so. And... it is not on a removable micro sd card that directory.

Comment: Ok, so what are my options to make file visible in the gallery?

Comment: You cannot make THAT file visible.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question. Step 1: File on server, Step 3: File visible in gallery. What is step 2?