# MediaStore creates a new file with instead of overwriting the existing one

Tags: android, kotlin, mediastore

I want to write to a file periodically and always replace it if already exists. The problem is that, using `MediaStore`, instead of overwriting the file, it creates a new one with the same name and appends a number to it

```
fun exportToFile(fileName: String, content: String) {
    // save to downloads folder
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    }

    val extVolumeUri: Uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
    val fileUri = context.contentResolver.insert(extVolumeUri, contentValues)

    // save file
    if (fileUri != null) {
        val os = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(fileUri, "wt")

        if (os != null) {
            os.write(content.toByteArray())
            os.close()
        }
    }
}
```

If I call `exportToFile("test.txt", "Hello world")`, it writes a file *test.txt*. If I call the same function again, it creates a new one called *test(1).txt* in the same folder. How do I override this and make it write to the same file?

Comment: Perhaps you should not be using `MediaStore`, especially for a text file. Even if you are sure that you should be using `MediaStore`, probably you would need to query to see if the file already exists, rather than `insert()` a new file each time.

Comment: Or easier you would remember the fileUri and use it again.

Comment: Your method does create a new file everytime, if you want to overwrite the same file you should first look up the file (by file name or else), then overwrite it, you can check out my full answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62879112/3466808

Comment: Thanks. I think that I need to query it because this file is supposed to be there even if I uninstall and reinstall the application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Sam Chen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62879112/3466808) and with some adaptations, this is my Kotlin solution

```
fun exportToFile(fileName: String, content: String) {
    val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain")
        put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    }

    val extVolumeUri: Uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")

    // query for the file
    val cursor: Cursor? = context.contentResolver.query(
        extVolumeUri,
        null,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME + " = ? AND " + MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE + " = ?",
        arrayOf(fileName, "text/plain"),
        null
    )

    var fileUri: Uri? = null

    // if file found
    if (cursor != null && cursor.count > 0) {
        // get URI
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            val nameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
            if (nameIndex > -1) {
                val displayName = cursor.getString(nameIndex)
                if (displayName == fileName) {
                    val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
                    if (idIndex > -1) {
                        val id = cursor.getLong(idIndex)
                        fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(extVolumeUri, id)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        cursor.close()
    } else {
        // insert new file otherwise
        fileUri = context.contentResolver.insert(extVolumeUri, contentValues)
    }

    if (fileUri != null) {
        val os = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(fileUri, "wt")

        if (os != null) {
            os.write(content.toByteArray())
            os.close()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this working for you ? I am trying to do the same but the cursor is always 0 & creates new file every single time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but with `RELATIVE_PATH`. Turns out I was missing a trailing slash. When inserting the file, it's ok to leave out the trailing slash, as it will be added automatically, but when used in the WHERE clause, it wouldn't match on equality.