# Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated. Alternative?

Tags: android, maui

I'm currently building a .Net Maui App that is only targeting android. I need to save some data in the public external storage that I can access and copy to my PC and that persists even if I uninstall the app. I choose the Documents directory.

The following does the job:

```
string dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments).AbsolutePath
```

But I get a warning from my IDE that GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory is deprecated.

I've found several postings that

```
Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDocuments)
```

will also work, but that does not return the same result.
The deprecated method returns

```
/storage/emulated/0/Documents
```

while the other one returns

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.companyname.myappname/files/Documents
```

Hence the appname is in the path, this is not persistent in case the app is uninstalled. So what is the correct way to get the public external documents directory?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)
Says it is. I'm confused.

Comment: it is depreciated, does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468733/15749574) help?

Comment: No it is not depeecated anymore. Use it.

Comment: I see it is deprecated from 29 on the official page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done a sample to test the MediaStore and the Context api. According to your description, you want to save some data to the file in the Document folder.

**For the Context**

All the files or directories you get from it belong to the application, when user uninstall the app from the devices, all of these will be deleted from the device. So this doesn't meet the requirement.

**For the MediaStore**

This api can be used to create file in the public folder, but the file can just be accessed by the app which create it. When user uninstall the application, you can't access it either.

And the google suggest the developer use the `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` to let the user create a file by himself and then user can open it by the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

So even though the `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` method has marked as deprecated, it is the easier way to get the result you want.

For more information, you can check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511147/create-copy-file-in-android-q-using-mediastore) and the [official document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files).

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. I am just worried that this code will no longer work in future adroid versions. Maybe I can drop the requirement that the data needs to stay after unsintalling the app.

Comment: Actually, the `Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated from the android api 29, I tested it in the android 12 and it still worked. In addition, if 
 all the app's data can still keep on the device when the app uninstalled without notifying the user, the storage will be limited. @Neralem

Comment: @Neralem - even if Android completely drops the API in future android, any app currently in app store won't suddenly stop working: the future Android OS will recognize backward compatibility for at least one more version. So you deal with it when you attempt to update your app, and instead of being deprecated it does not exist. So you will know, as soon as you attempt build with newer SDK.