# How to read a file directly from external download directory on Android 10 (Q)

Tags: android, storage

I am trying to read a file from the download folder on Android Q by doing this:

```java
        File downloadDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File f = new File(downloadDir, "some-existing-file");
        if(!f.exists()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }

        Uri furi = Uri.fromFile(f);
        try {
            ParcelFileDescriptor des = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(
                    furi, "r", null);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I also set `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in the manifest, and requested `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` runtime permissions.

The file exists but when trying to open the file descriptor, an exception arises: 
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`.

I read the [changes made](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) in Android Q storage, but could not figure out how can I just read the file without having user interaction.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just open the `File` directly (e.g., with `FileInputStream`)? Why are you using a `Uri` and a `ContentResolver`? Bear in mind that even with `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` that you still need to request runtime permissions. Also, where are you getting `downloadDir` from?

Comment: `FileInputStream` I receive the same outcome. I didn't mentioning but i did ask for the needed runtime permissions.

Comment: Are other locations working? In other words, is your problem limited to this one directory, or are you unable to access files everywhere on external storage?

Comment: Just tried with `Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS` and `Environment.DCIM`, received the same outcome.

Comment: Then perhaps there is an issue with where and how you applied `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`. Can you post your manifest?

Comment: Sure: here it is: https://pastebin.com/cjvPMVrf

Comment: OK, that looks normal. I and others have used `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` without a problem, so I am uncertain as to what is going wrong here for you.

Comment: It can be hep you .[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56468733/8956604)

Comment: Kasim, the answer you provided is for writing files, not reading them :(.

Comment: CommonsWare, do you might have a code sample that work for you? I'd be happy to take a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After too many hours of trying to figure out what the hell is going on, I managed to find a solution.

I addded to the manifest:

```xml
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

When rebuilding and reinstalling directly from Android Studio, the build system or android runtime does not register a change in the manifest, and the request for  `requestLegacyExternalStorage` does not register.

I fixed it by completely uninstalling the app: `adb uninstall com.example.app` and installing it again from android studio.

Comment: Please note that adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` is not safe as it's a temporary flag and would be removed soon. Also targeting SDK 29 for new and old app is going to be mandatory on play store by end of the year. So please refrain from suggesting this as a solution, and using this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 6 (Marshmallow) some of critical permissions should be granted at runtime by the user so he/she will know what things can your app access.
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34722591/8136868) is all what you need

**EDIT**

add these to manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

then add this code to your oncreate method

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    2000);
        }
```

this will popup the user a dialog to agree permissions. if the user agrees `onRequestPermissionsResult` method will be called, so override `onRequestPermissionsResult` like this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && requestCode == 2000) {
        //do what you want with files
    }
}
```

just pay attention that I set request code to 2000. it's optional.

Comment: Hi, please note that I said that i asked for the runtime permissions.

Comment: @v0idbar it is interesting that I ran into a problem like yours today. below link helped me. try it.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38858040/8136868

Answer (score 0):

This method was deprecated in **API level 29**. To improve user privacy, direct access to shared/external storage devices is deprecated. When an app targets **Build.VERSION_CODES.Q**, the path returned from this method is no longer directly accessible to apps. Apps can continue to access content stored on shared/external storage by migrating to alternatives such as **Context#getExternalFilesDir(String)**, **MediaStore**, or **Intent#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT**.

Copied from Android documents.[docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment)