# Share image code working fine with Android version 9 and below but isn't working for Android version 10

Tags: android, android-fileprovider, android-sharing

I want to share an image file including a url to the other applications and my code is working fine with android 9 and below but it's not working with android version 10. I'm not able to figure out the problem yet. Here is the code and please let me know if i'm missing something.

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        path = args[0];
        String idStr = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File dir = new File (filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/Top Images/");
        dir.mkdirs();
        String fileName = idStr;
        file = new File(dir, fileName);
        Ion.with(getApplicationContext()).load(path)
                .write(file);
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/gif");
        share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, FileProvider.getUriForFile(SlideImageActivity.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",file));

        // SHARE URL
        share.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,getString(R.string.play_share_app));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share the photo"));
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539/getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-deprecated-in-android-q

Comment: Please explain in detail what "it's not working" means. Note that you can neither read nor write in that directory by default on Android 10+.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have seen your answer on another post that's accepted and I'll try that. Error is just like "File format not supported when I share in whatsapp"

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir this link is helpful. thanks brother