# How can i save captured image to gallery?

Tags: java, android

I have some codes like this for saving image to gallery,

But it says deprecated for "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory"

I know i need to use MediaStore or getExternalFilesDir or something

But don't know how to

Thanks

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
        return image;
    }
```

Comment: Firstly, I want to ask did you make a permission in manifest ?

Comment: Yes CAMERA , READ AND WRITE

Comment: i just have askCameraPermission forget about storage :(

Comment: What i mean ask permission in Runtime.

Comment: Yes now i have.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539/getexternalstoragepublicdirectory-deprecated-in-android-q

Answer (score 0):

try this for new Function getExternalFilesDir

```
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer lot but it is not getting into Gallery it's saving into myapp.files.Pictures how can we make the saving directory gallery(public)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line of code:

```
File storageDir = getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

To:

```
File storageDir = applicationContext().getFilesDir()
```