# How to set and get apk file from download folder on android 11

Tags: java, android, file

After downloading the apk file, I need to find it in the Donwloads folder, run and install it, it all works up to Android 11, but now there is a problem. I think this is due to a change in file access, but strangely, it works if there are no files, and the download is the first, but if there is already a file there (for example test.apk), it downloads the second apk, call it test-1.apk and does not see them anymore.

In older versions, I got files like this:

```
    //set file
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, APK_NAME);

    final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);

    //get file
    final String path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS) + "/" + APK_NAME;
    final FilenameFilter filenameFilter = (file, s) -> APK_NAME.equals(s);
    final File[] files = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).listFiles(filenameFilter);
```

and used the "files" array but getExternalStoragePublicDirectory is now deprecated and one should use something like there https://stackoverflow.com/a/57649669/6040706
But I don't understand how I can use this, can anyone help?

Comment: If the download manager is ready you get a nice uri. You can use that uri in action_view.

Comment: Download manager saves apk file to Download folder, and I want to get it from there, or get uri, but how I can get it?

Comment: Use a broadcast receiver to get an uri from download manager when ready.