# MediaRecorder prepare() failed /storage/emulated/0/: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)

Tags: java, android, mediarecorder, android-external-storage

I am trying to record audio on my Android 12 Device with `File and Media Permission` granted but `recorder.prepare();` throws

`prepare() failed /storage/emulated/0/Music/Exotel/Media/Exotel Audio/Voice Messages/Exotel Temp/Exotel_Voice1658709937668.3gpp: open failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)`

I am using [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder) but they are saving recording into app specific storage(`getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();`) and i am saving on external public storage
`String TempPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + subfolder;` . No matter what i try i still get the same error whenever i tried to save into external shared storage.

Here is my code:

```java
String subfolder = "Exotel/Media/Exotel Audio/Voice Messages/Exotel Temp";
String time = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
String filename = Session.getUserFname()+"_Voice"+time+".3gp";
String TempPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + subfolder;
File dir = new File(TempPath);

if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
}

TempPath = TempPath+"/"+filename;
Log.d(TAG, "onTouch: Temp Path "+TempPath);

recorder = new MediaRecorder();
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
recorder.setOutputFile(TempPath);
recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();
} catch (IOException | IllegalStateException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "prepare() failed "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Yes you cannot create your own subfolders on external storage on Android 11+ devices. Use an existing public folder.

Comment: @blackapps I'm creating app directory inside existing music directory like others app do. For ex in picture folder you can see different app subfolder like Twitter, Instagram etc.

Comment: @blackapps i can see directory created by file.mkdirs but the file is not created. Any idea?

Comment: Not all extensions are permitted in public Music directory. Try .mp3.

Comment: if (!dir.exists()){
                         if (!   dir.mkdirs()) return:
                        }

Comment: @blackapps Is there any documentation for extension permitted ? Directory is created everytime but not the recorded file

Comment: `Try .mp3.` You are not reacting on this suggestion. Nor on the mkdirs advise. Any reason?

Comment: @blackapps mp3 works but creating .mp3 is not suitable in our case for recording and i mentioned in my comment that i can see directory but not file. Is there any way to save recordings in music folder?

Comment: If .mp3 works than in Music folder isnt it? So you would see it. There would be a file then. You are unclear.

Comment: @blackapps I can see mp3 file in music folder but i need to create 3gp for recording through MediaRecorder

Comment: Well, as said before, and as you saw, not all extensions are permitted in Music folder.

Comment: @blackapps is there any documentation where i can see allowed extensions in music folder and where else i can store recordings then

Comment: A .3gp file is a video file extension. Not a music file extension. You could try public Movies or Videos directory.

Comment: @blackapps  The offical documentation of Android using 3gp you can check i mentioned link in my question

Comment: It is unclear what you wanna say. Or what should i check? Repeat: not all file extensions are permitted in Music folder.

Comment: @Ritu, unfortunately, getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() method is deprecated, you should use [MediaStore API](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) to work with public shared directories on Android 11+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)) method is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56468539) in API level 29 (Android 10).

If you want to save a file into a public shareable directory you have to use [MediaStore API](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media). I also recommend taking a look at [all options](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) for storing files on Android.

If you have no problems with saving your recordings into a cache directory (by using the code from the official docs). Then you can copy the file from the cache to the public directory using MediaStore API:

```java
private void copyToPublicDirectory(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = createInputStream(filename);
    OutputStream outputStream = createOutputStream(filename);
    copy(inputStream, outputStream);
}

private InputStream createInputStream(String filename) throws IOException {
    File cacheDirectory = getExternalCacheDir();
    if (cacheDirectory == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Cache is not currently available");
    return new FileInputStream(new File(cacheDirectory, filename));
}

private OutputStream createOutputStream(String filename) throws IOException {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
    Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, contentValues);
    if (uri == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot insert file: " + filename);
    OutputStream outputStream = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
    if (outputStream == null)
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot open uri: " + uri);
    return outputStream;
}

private void copy(InputStream source, OutputStream target) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    int length;
    while ((length = source.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        target.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
}
```

**Note:** 3gp recordings have `video/3gpp` mime type. And it will be saved into the `Movies` directory (as @blackapps already said). If you want to record a file in audio format and save it into the `Music` directory, then do the following:

1. Change content uri from `MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` to `MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` in the code above.
2. Use OGG format in your MediaRecorder setup (OGG format is available only for Android API 29 and higher):

   ```java
   setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.OGG)
   setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.OPUS)
   ```

**PS:** don't forget to add all necessary permissions to make things work.